# Bitcoin transaction stuck

Tags: blockchain, child-pays-for-parent

I sent a bitcoin transaction and after sending it I realized that the fee was too low.

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/a398c4a2db165bd35435e381a6d185a14aa7a3df40aeca157dd89e4efd2e20d1

in an attempt to correct it, later on, I sent another transaction to the same address with a higher fee.

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/92b33d498a35d47f03eee14f258cf9b3f015a5d12856eb05e47534e664344239

as I read about Child pays for Parent, but still it didn't work. The second transaction went through and the first one is still there. Did I do something wrong? Is there anything I can do to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child pays for parent (CPFP) transaction is based on the assumption that the child actually spends the output created by the first transaction.

In your case, your second transaction does not actually spend the output of the first transaction - this allows it to be confirmed without any relation to the previous one.

That said, your fee is not so low that it will never confirm - transactions with that feerate are cleared out every day or two, usually. You will likely be fine if you just wait.

If you are in a hurry, you can use your wallet to make another transaction spending the unconfirmed output - note that this is not an option if the address you sent the coins to belongs to an exchange or hosted wallet where you cannot control which outputs/keys are used for a new transaction.

Comment: I see, so basically, I just spent unnecessary fee money in the second transaction lol. Thank you!